# Retrieve the value given to HasMaxValue at runtime

Tags: c#, validation, entity-framework-core

I've got a code first EF Core model. Some of the columns use the `HasMaxLength(X)` fluent syntax to limit the length of these columns. Currently these limits are only enforced by the database and i'd like to find out before hitting the database when a string has become to long.

Fluent config example:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(p => p.SomeStringProperty)
                    .HasMaxLength(200);
            });
```

Now i would like to get the `HasMaxLength` value back at runtime when i only have a DBContext at hand. Is that possilbe?

Thinking about something like: `ctx.Set<SomeEntity>.SomeStringProperty.MaxLength()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Thinking about something like: `ctx.Set<SomeEntity>.SomeStringProperty.MaxLength()`

Almost. Just instead of `DbSet<T>` you need to use the EF Core model metadata services, staring with `Context.Model` property, and then `FindEntityType`, `GetProperties` or `FindProperty` etc., for instance

```
ctx.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(SomeEntity))
    .FindProperty(nameof(SomeEntity.SomeStringProperty))
    .GetMaxLength()
```

**Reference:** [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata?view=efcore-2.1)